# How can I access the virtualenv management commands?

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv

I can't access any of the virtualenv management commands, such Get-VirtualEnvironment.
I did the following in Windows-XP:

1. Installed C:\Python27.
2. Installed pip and setuptools in C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages.
3. Using PowerShell, ran "pip install virtualenv".
4. Created the environment variable WORKON_HOME = (A local directory).

However, when I run `Get-Command virtualenv` I get one line as a response, not the list of virtualenv commands.

Answer (score 0):

**First:** Install virtualenv with pip install (in your Python `\Scripts` dir)

```
C:\Python2\Scripts>pip install virtualenv
Downloading/unpacking virtualenv
  Downloading virtualenv-1.11.5.tar.gz (1.8MB): 1.8MB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package virtualenv

    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'do
cs\_templates'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'do
cs\_build'
Installing collected packages: virtualenv
  Running setup.py install for virtualenv

    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'do
cs\_templates'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'do
cs\_build'
    Installing virtualenv-script.py script to C:\Python2\Scripts
    Installing virtualenv.exe script to C:\Python2\Scripts
    Installing virtualenv.exe.manifest script to C:\Python2\Scripts
    Installing virtualenv-2.7-script.py script to C:\Python2\Scripts
    Installing virtualenv-2.7.exe script to C:\Python2\Scripts
    Installing virtualenv-2.7.exe.manifest script to C:\Python2\Scripts
Successfully installed virtualenv
Cleaning up...
```

**Second:** Create the virtual environment called env01 (or you like).

```
C:\Python2\Scripts>virtualenv ..\env01
New python executable in ..\env01\Scripts\python.exe
Installing setuptools, pip...done.
```

**Third:** Go to en virtualenv dir created

```
C:\Python2\Scripts>cd ..\env01

C:\Python2\env01>dir
 El volumen de la unidad C es ********
 El número de serie del volumen es: ****-****

 Directorio de C:\Python2\env01

03/05/2014  19:25    <DIR>          .
03/05/2014  19:25    <DIR>          ..
15/01/2014  16:33    <DIR>          Include
03/05/2014  19:25    <DIR>          Lib
03/05/2014  19:25    <DIR>          Scripts
               0 archivos              0 bytes
               5 dirs  11.779.756.032 bytes libres
```

**Fourth:** Execute the `activate.bat` script in `<your_virtualenv>\Scripts\` dir

```
C:\Python2\env01>.\Scripts\activate
**(env01) C:\Python2\env01>**
```

- Remind to deactivate your virtualenv with deactivate.bat script:

  (env01) C:\Python2\env01>deactivate

  C:\Python2\env01>
- It works for Python3 too.